# How can I place a JLabel on a specific position within a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

We're about to create an online based Space Invaders-game with implemented graphics. I've been reading about JFrames, JPanels and JLabels in order to create a window with a grid where the ships and monsters will be placed in.

So, here's the thing, I've been looking through the different layouts that exists, but nothing really seems to fit our purpose. I would like a simple JFrame with the possibility of placing JLabel-objects on a certain position (with setBounds(), setLocation() or something similar). This requires setLayout(null) which I've heard isn't a good solution? I was thinking of having objects in a fixed 30x30px size, and a fixed window size of 600x600px (giving me a grid of 20*20).

Anyhow, I've been trying to get it to work with setLayout(null), but without any results. If I apply a layout, say FlowLayout, the ship is visible, but stuck in either LEFT, CENTER or MIDDLE.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    JPanel p = new JPanel(null);

    public GUI() {

        try{
            this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("graphics/bg.png")))));
        }catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Image does not exist");
        }

        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(600,600);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void placeShip1() {
        ImageIcon ship2 = new ImageIcon("graphics/ship2.png");
        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(ship2);

        imageLabel.setBounds(200,200,30,30);
        p.add(imageLabel);
        p.setOpaque(false);
        p.setSize(600, 600);

        this.add(p);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

I really can't see why it doesn't work. I mean, all I want is my JFrame with a background image and with an object on a certain position, but instead the object doesn't show at all.

The main reason for wanting to use setLayout(null) is because I was thinking of using a method translating our grid coordinates to the JFrame, simply mapping each coordinate to respective cell.

Comment: *"We're about to create an online based Space Invaders-game with implemented graphics"* - This automatically suggests to me that you DON'T want to use `JLabel`'s or any other components (other then a `JPanel` as the primary rendering surface) and instead what to start learning how to perform custom painting, which will give you much more control (and a lot less of issues). Start by having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Comment: The problem you're having comes a lot down to how the layout management API works, so by removing it, you start running to other problems.  Normally, you would use `revalidate` and `repaint` after you've changed the UI, but `revalidate` relates to the layout management API. Also, I don't see anywhere you're using `placeShip1`

Comment: Thank you very much! I suspected something like that, because JFrame seems to have more focus on interactive interfaces like menus etc. 

Ah, and "placeShip1" is called from another class. I just thought it was unnecessary to include. :)

Comment: Well, more to the point, the controls you're talking about do.  `JFrame` (and `JPanel`, which is where I suggest you start) are just containers

Comment: You could have a look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080148/rotating-a-polygon-in-java) which I just provided an example to which uses custom painting and animates a custom shape around the screen