# How to use getWidth() and getHeight() to center the star shape in java

Tags: java, swing

I'm having problem centering the star shape. The problem is that I hard coded the points for each coordinate. And the problem with this is that Im not getting the right position although I created a perfect 5 star. On more problem is that what if I want to rescale the shape to make it bigger or small by clicking a button?
Here's my code.

```
public void run() {
            DifferentShapes panel = new DifferentShapes();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Different Shapes");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(400,400);
            frame.setVisible(true);  
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.setJMenuBar(panel.getMenuBAr());
        }

    public void star(Graphics shape) {
    //        int sizeReq = 1;
    int [] starX =  new int[] {250, 262, 304, 268, 278, 250, 222, 232, 196, 238};
    int []starY =  new int[] {200, 236, 236, 254, 296, 272, 296, 254, 236, 236};
    shape.fillPolygon(starX, starY, starX.length);    

}
```

Comment: You could use the [`Polygon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) class instead, which has `getBounds` and `tranlsate` functionality ... which is why we keep suggesting that you use the "shapes" API instead.  You can see an example in [Drawing Arbitrary Shapes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html) and some more information in [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html). And before you ask, `Graphics2D` can support `draw` and `fill` of `java.awt.Shape` based classes

Comment: Hard-coding the points isn't a "problem" in my mind

Comment: And you could have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080148/rotating-a-polygon-in-java/34080399#34080399) for a demonstration of the power of the shapes API

Comment: what is the problem now and what do you want to achieve? "not getting the right position although I created a perfect 5 star": what does this mean?

Comment: @gpasch When I created the shape it's not position on the center because im I just hardcoded the points.

Comment: but you are satisfied with the shape? to keep the hardcoded numbers?

Comment: @gpasch not so it's not position on the center

Answer (score 5):

## Without the Shapes API

You could spend a lot of time manually translating the polygon array, but a better solution might be to translate the polygon to `0x0`, so that the top/left corner will be at `0x0`

Basically, I calculated the min/max values for each array and then subtracted the "min" value from all the values...

```
protected static int[] minMax(int[] values) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int value : values) {
        min = Math.min(min, value);
        max = Math.max(max, value);
    }

    return new int[]{min, max};
}

protected static int[] normalise(int[] values, int min) {
    for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
        values[index] = values[index] - min;
    }
    return values;
}
```

So starting with...

```
[250, 262, 304, 268, 278, 250, 222, 232, 196, 238]
[200, 236, 236, 254, 296, 272, 296, 254, 236, 236]
```

translated to...

```
[54, 66, 108, 72, 82, 54, 26, 36, 0, 42]
[0, 36, 36, 54, 96, 72, 96, 54, 36, 36]
```

which when painted, looks something like...

[image: Top/Left]

You're probably thinking about now, well, that's not much good, I want it in the centre, but to get in the center, we need the width and height of the polygon

To achieve this, I took the translated arrays and passed them through the `minMax` method and used the second element of the return value, which gave me a value of `108x96` (`width`x`height`), now we have the information we need to center the shape

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics copy = g.create();
    int x = (getWidth() - maxWidth) / 2;
    int y = (getHeight() - maxHeight) / 2;
    copy.translate(x, y);
    copy.fillPolygon(starX, starY, starX.length);
    copy.dispose();
}
```

Basically, all this does is uses the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` values to calculate the center location within the current component, translate the `Graphics` context to the appropriate offset and paints the polygon.  The translation moves the origin position (the `0x0` point of the `Graphics` context) which allows use to change where the polygon will be painted.

[image: Star in the middle]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    protected static int[] minMax(int[] values) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int value : values) {
            min = Math.min(min, value);
            max = Math.max(max, value);
        }

        return new int[]{min, max};
    }

    protected static int[] normalise(int[] values, int min) {
        for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
            values[index] = values[index] - min;
        }
        return values;
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int starX[];
        private int starY[];

        private int maxWidth, maxHeight;

        public TestPane() {
            starX = new int[]{250, 262, 304, 268, 278, 250, 222, 232, 196, 238};
            starY = new int[]{200, 236, 236, 254, 296, 272, 296, 254, 236, 236};

            int[] minMaxX = minMax(starX);
            int[] minMaxY = minMax(starY);

            starX = normalise(starX, minMaxX[0]);
            starY = normalise(starY, minMaxY[0]);

            minMaxX = minMax(starX);
            minMaxY = minMax(starY);

            maxWidth = minMaxX[1];
            maxHeight = minMaxY[1];
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics copy = g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - maxWidth) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - maxHeight) / 2;
            copy.translate(x, y);
            copy.fillPolygon(starX, starY, starX.length);
            copy.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

So, about know, you should see the importance of using a `0x0` origin for your shapes.

Have a look at [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Transforming Shapes, Text, and Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html) for more details

### Scaling...

Scaling can be done through `Graphics2D#scale`...

[image: Scale]

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    double scale = slider.getValue() / 100d;
    int x = (getWidth() - maxWidth) / 2;
    int y = (getHeight() - maxHeight) / 2;
    copy.translate(x, y);
    copy.scale(scale, scale);
    copy.fillPolygon(starX, starY, starX.length);
    copy.dispose();
}
```

but this scales the pixels which might not give the results you want.

Before someone jumps down my throat, if you want to get it centered again, you'll need to scale the `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` values as well

## With the Shapes API

As I've said in the past, you will get better results with the 2D shapes API, they are self contained, they are easily moved and you will get a better results when they are scaled

For example, using the "translated" values from above, you should create a nice custom, re-usable, class...

```
public class StarShape extends Path2D.Double {

    public StarShape() {
        moveTo(54, 0);
        lineTo(66, 36);
        lineTo(108, 36);
        lineTo(75, 54);
        lineTo(82, 96);
        lineTo(54, 72);
        lineTo(26, 96);
        lineTo(36, 54);
        lineTo(0, 36);
        lineTo(42, 36);
        closePath();
    }

}
```

Know, I don't know about you, but that is so much easier to read and you could easily plot this on some graph paper.

Now it's easily filled by doing something as simple as...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.fill(new StarShape());
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

But, wait, we want it centered, all to easy...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    Rectangle bounds = starShape.getBounds();
    int x = (getWidth() - bounds.width) / 2;
    int y = (getHeight() - bounds.height) / 2;
    g2d.fill(starShape.createTransformedShape(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y)));
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

Well, that was a lot less code than the non-shapes API approach...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class StarShape extends Path2D.Double {

        public StarShape() {
            moveTo(54, 0);
            lineTo(66, 36);
            lineTo(108, 36);
            lineTo(75, 54);
            lineTo(82, 96);
            lineTo(54, 72);
            lineTo(26, 96);
            lineTo(36, 54);
            lineTo(0, 36);
            lineTo(42, 36);
            closePath();
        }

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private StarShape starShape;

        public TestPane() {
            starShape = new StarShape();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            Rectangle bounds = starShape.getBounds();
            int x = (getWidth() - bounds.width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - bounds.height) / 2;
            g2d.fill(starShape.createTransformedShape(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y)));
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

### Scaling

Generally speaking, scaling uses the same process as translating, BUT, what you get, is the benefit that you can scale a `Shape` and then translate it separately, allowing you to get the `Rectangle` bounds of the scaled `Shape` independently.  It also scales the vector (points) and not pixels which will give you a better result...

[image: Scales]

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    double scale = slider.getValue() / 100d;
    Shape shape = starShape.createTransformedShape(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));
    Rectangle bounds = shape.getBounds();
    int x = (getWidth() - bounds.width) / 2;
    int y = (getHeight() - bounds.height) / 2;
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    path.append(shape.getPathIterator(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y)), true);
    g2d.fill(path);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```

So, the short answer is, use the Shapes API, the long answer is, use the Shapes API, you won't need to reinvent the wheel for each problem you face

Comment: Why do you need to create a copy of Graphics?

Comment: @viniciusdenovaes Mostly, this is a personal thing, but a `Graphics` reference is a shared context, this gets passed to all the components which need to be painted, so any changes on component makes will be passed on to the the next component which needs to be painted, so unless that component reverts the changes, it can have unexpected and undesirable results.  So, as a simple precaution, I always have a `create`/`dispose` cycle in my code, it's created using templates and key shortcuts, so it tends to end up every. Not required for this example, but it's not a bad practice

Comment: @viniciusdenovaes In the first series of examples, I translate the context, if this was left unaltered, it would filter down to other components, causing them to be also offset.  Same thing for scaling.  The `create`/`dispose` workflow makes it simple to make modifications to the state of the graphics context in a isolate manner, without needing a lot of code to undo those changes manually

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using the [Shape Utils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) helper class to generate the star for you so you don't need to manually calculate all the points on the star.

Basically you just need two lines of code to use the class:

```
star = ShapeUtils.radiusShape(10, 55, 22);
```

This will generate a star with 10 points alternating from 55 to 22 pixels from the center.

The first point generated will be on the horizontal line. Since there are 5 large points this means they will be generate every 72 degrees. Since you want the top point to be on the vertical axis you will then need to rotate all the points by -18 degrees:

```
star = ShapeUtils.rotate(star, -18);
```

A simple example showing how to paint the star centered in a panel is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShapeSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    private Shape star;

    public ShapeSSCCE()
    {
        star = ShapeUtils.radiusShape(10, 55, 22);
        star = ShapeUtils.rotate(star, -18);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        Rectangle bounds = star.getBounds();

        return new Dimension(bounds.width, bounds.height);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        Rectangle bounds = star.getBounds();
        int x = (getWidth()  - bounds.width)  / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - bounds.height) / 2;
        g2d.translate(x, y);
        g2d.fill( star );
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShapeSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ShapeSSCCE() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Try the code with/without the rotated shape to see the difference.

If you don't want to do custom painting then you can use the `ShapeIcon` class also found in the above link. Then you can treat the star like an Icon and add it to a label:

```
Shape star = ShapeUtils.radiusShape(10, 55, 22);
star = ShapeUtils.rotate(star, -18);
ShapeIcon starIcon = new ShapeIcon(star, Color.RED);
JLabel starLabel = new JLabel( starIcon );
```

> I want to rescale the shape to make it bigger or small by clicking a button?

You could:

1. Create a new shape using the `ShapeUtils` class with new values
2. Scale the existing shape using an AffineTransform. Check out the ShapeUtils.rotate(...) method to see how this is done for a rotation. The logic would be similar for the scaling.
3. Dynamically scale the shape when you paint it using an AffineTransform. Read the Graphics2D class for information about setting a transform.